# Windows 7 64 bit on Intel Core 2 Duo T5800

Tags: 32-vs-64-bit

I have an [Intel Core 2 Duo](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=35581) T5800 processor in my old laptop. The specs on Intel says it is 64 bit. I remember my vendor telling me it is a 32 bit laptop and I have 32 bit Windows 7 installed. How can I check whether it supports 64 bit Windows OS.

```
   Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (6.1, Build 7600) (7600.win7_rtm.090713-1255)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
       System Model: Inspiron 1525                   
               BIOS: Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A16
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5800  @ 2.00GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.0GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3574MB RAM
```

Answer (score 5):

It supports 64-bit Windows 7. All Merom processors are 64-bit capable.

Answer (score 4):

I would get [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and make sure it lists the CPU as supporting "EM64T" (which is what Intel calls the AMD64 extension).  It will be listed on the first tab under Instructions.

Comment: yes, it does list EM64T. So it is safe to purchase a 64 bit Windows? My 500 MB of RAM is getting wasted since I use 32 bit

Comment: I can't think of any reason 64-bit Windows 7 wouldn't work.

Comment: Milen, before you "buy" it, check with the laptop maker to see if they have a re-install disk for 64-bit, and if not, see if you can procure a 64-bit (PROBABLY) OEM disk. You have the rights to either the 64-bit or 32-bit version, so you just need the media and 64-bit should work with the key on the label your got with your computer, provided you find the right disk. A replacement disk is usually only about $20.

Comment: This, by the way, is a case where even if you used something like bit torrent to get the media, you are not pirating software.

Answer (score 1):

Run [this program](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm), be sure 64bit is not blocked in the bios. You may have to enable it in the bios.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the CPU itself should support a 64-bit operating system; but the notebook vendor may state that it is a '32-bit notebook' because they didn't, and have no plans to, write 64-bit drivers for the devices in the notebook (LAN, video, etc.).

So you may want to check with the notebook vendor's website to ensure there are 64-bit drivers available before blowing away your 32-bit OS. :)